# Let users link webcams in website to stream

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, webcam, live-streaming

I can't find any concrete solutions for my scenario yet.
I'm mainly using PHP (CodeIgniter) and AngularJS

I want to be able to start an online game (lets say Darts)
When you play online against an other player, you should be able to turn webcams on, as a proof that the scores are correct. 
I know this is possible with Google Hangouts, but the hangouts cams will run out of the main window.

I also want to make spectators possible, so they see the cams as a LIVE-stream. With hangouts, everyone has to join the hangouts chat, I don't want people to do that for the user-experience.

So I want to link two or more webcams in a webpage and be able to watch it as a spectator. (Without having to much serverload, if possible)

Any thoughts on this one? I'm really stuck...

Comment: Have you looked into WebRTC...? Or any Flash-based streaming solutions?

Comment: I want to avoid Flash if possible and WebRTC doesn't have the coverage I want (Safari isn't ready for example) http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/

Comment: Then you'll have a pretty hard time getting this off the ground. No WebRTC and no Flash leaves you with basically 0% install base for anything. Unless you're happy to write your own plugin and have visitors install it.

Comment: Well I Guess Flash isn't a terrible solution ofcourse, Hangouts is nice because of the cross-platform compatibility. I might give WebRTC a try. I think using Chrome or FF is more user friendly than having to install flash or create a hangouts account

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use rtmp / rtsp server for this scenario. There are several rtsp server available.

- Red5 http://osflash.org/red5
- Wowza http://www.wowzamedia.com/
- WebOrb http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products.html
- ErlyVideo http://erlyvideo.org/
- RubyIzumi http://code.google.com/p/rubyizumi/
- RTMPD http://www.rtmpd.com/
- Cygnal http://wiki.gnashdev.org/Cygnal
- RTMPy http://rtmpy.org/wiki/RTMP
- RTMPlite http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/
- MammothServer (OpenFMS) http://mammothserver.org/

In my opinion Wowza and Red5 will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't want to stream a video myself, I want two people (contenders) to be able to turn their own cams on and create a live stream so visitors can see it also. like http://www.scriptcam.com/ (Just found that one)

Comment: Definitely wowza provides the same. Just refer to examples you will find the live chat example there.

In Red5 you may need to convert stream using ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I filled in the contact form at Wowza!